# How skip tfa setup phase in flask-security-too

Tags: two-factor-authentication, flask-security

I'd like to have defaulted up to sms the tfa method and skip the user choice on it, providing the code automatically on login and then verifying it.

I tried setting into the db manually sms but the setup form is shown anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Digging a bit into the code, i saw it requires both method and secret set into the db to consider user already set-upped.
Creating a script in init for giving all users a tf_totp_secret solved.

```
for user in User.all():
    if user.tf_totp_secret is None:
        user.tf_totp_secret = flask_security.twofactor.generate_totp()
```

Comment: Be aware that in 3.4 (out soon) that method has moved (it was never public). Still accessible. Any reason you didn't just change TWO_FACTOR_ENABLED_METHODS=["sms"] so that they only have one choice?

Comment: I don't want that the setup form is shown to the user, i want that sms is the method (achieved by setting TWO_FACTOR_ENABLED_METHODS as you suggest) and i have already the phone number (that shouldn't be changeable). Setting tf_totp_secret  allowed me to skip setup form.